# Storing multiple Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have a class which implements `Runnable` interface, and I am to make 5 instances of given class in the main program. I would like to store them either in array, or a collection. Since the class implements `Runnable` it is my understanding that the only way I can store it is in a thread container such as `Thread[]`.  However if I do this I can't use classes overridden `toString()` method for example, or any other custom method/field.

```
public class LittleClass implements Runnable{
    public void run(){

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread[] smallClasses = new Thread[5];

    // initialize and so...

    smallClasses[i].customField//not accessible
    System.out.println(smallClasses[i])//gives Thread[Thread-X,X,]
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just store array of `LittleClass`?

Comment: If I did that then making a new Thread with Thread t = new Thread(new LittleClass()) wouldn't be storable in the LittleClass[] array, or did I miss something? :)

Comment: @Mr.Potson: There's nothing stopping you from creating your array or collection of LittleClass objects first, and then iterating through the array creating the threads. But more important you have missed Gray's answer. You'd better look at it and his tutorial as this is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using an `ExecutorService`.  Then you keep an array of your job classes and submit them to the service to be run.

```
// create a thread pool with as many workers as needed
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// submit your jobs which should implements Runnable
for (YourRunnable job : jobs) {
    threadPool.submit(job);
}
```

Once you have submitting your jobs, you shut down the service, wait for it to finish, and then you can interrogate your jobs to get information from them.

```
// shuts the pool down but the submitted jobs still run
threadPool.shutdown();
// wait for all of the jobs to finish
threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// now go back and print out your jobs
for (YourRunnable job : jobs) {
    System.out.println(jobs.toString());
}
```

Here's a [good tutorial on the subject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

Comment: But why to get it so complicated?

Comment: @Andrey: because this entity was created just for this situation. 1+

Comment: Because anytime someone has an array of threads they should use an `ExecutorService` @Audrey.  That's what they are for.

Comment: Always a +1 for "Don't use `Thread`s use an `ExecutorService`".

Comment: There is no array of threads here @Andrey.  Just an array of your job classes.  You could get more complicated and use `Future` but it wouldn't save much.

Comment: @Andrey: `"but array of threads is not disappearing anywhere."` -- please translate this. I see no array of Thread anywhere in the above solution. @ Gray: Future is useful if something needs to be returned.

Comment: Ugh, this method is a bit out of my current scope, but I will give it a try, if none other is presented I will accept it as answer. Thanks Gray.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom class which implements Runnable and then story an array of those custom classes.

So, for instance, in the code you wrote above, you can always use

```
LittleClass[] objs = new LittleClass[4];
for(int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
   objs[i] = new LittleClass();
}
```

Comment: How is that? Seems reasonable.

Comment: OK, I'll remove my down vote. But you do understand that there was no reason to recommend his class extend Thread, and many reasons not to do this.

Comment: I meant "implement Runnable" and I edited it to reflect that.